# What's the best way to lock a record while it is being updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

If I need to `SELECT` a value from a table column (happens to be the primary key column) based on a relatively complex `WHERE` clause in the stored procedure, and I then want to update that record without any other concurrent stored procedures `SELECT`ing the same record, is it as simple as just using a transaction?  Or do I also need to up the isolation to Repeatable Read?

It looks like this:

```
Alter Procedure Blah
As
Declare @targetval int
update table1 set field9 = 1, @targetval = field1 where field1 = (
SELECT TOP 1 field1
FROM table1 t
WHERE
(t.field2 = 'this') AND (t.field3 = 'that') AND (t.field4 = 'yep') AND (t.field9 <> 1))
return
```

I then get my targetval in my program so that I can do work on it, and meanwhile I don't have to worry about other worker threads grabbing the same targetval.

I'm talking SQL 2000, SQL 2005, and SQL 2008 here.

Comment: I'm not at all convinced the answer you accepted is correct. See the update in my answer for reasons why!

Comment: Seriously? this is what you have to go through? In Oracle you'd first do a SELECT with the clause FOR UPDATE... that would not allow another transaction to do the same. Then just do what you want and then commit;

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is to replicate the process which a Queue will do for you. Have you worked with Queues before?

Comment: RE: The point on queues a good article covering this (for 2005/2008 only though http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK` to the sub query should do it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Blah
AS
  DECLARE @targetval INT

  UPDATE table1
  SET    field9 = 1,
         @targetval = field1
  WHERE  field1 = (SELECT TOP 1 field1
                   FROM   table1 t WITH (rowlock, updlock)
                   WHERE  ( t.field2 = 'this' )
                          AND ( t.field3 = 'that' )
                          AND ( t.field4 = 'yep' )
                          AND ( t.field9 <> 1 ))

  RETURN
```

### Updated

The currently accepted answer to this question does not use `updlock`. I'm not at all convinced that this will work. As far as I can see from testing in this type of query with a sub query SQL Server will only take `S` locks for the sub query. Sometimes however the sub query will get optimised out so this approach might appear to work as in Query 2.

### Test Script - Setup

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
col char(40)
)

INSERT INTO test_table
SELECT NEWID() FROM sys.objects
```

### Query 1

```
update test_table
set col=NEWID()
where id=(SELECT top (1) id from test_table )
```

[image: Plan for id query]
[image: Trace for id query]

### Query 2

```
update test_table
set col=NEWID()
where id=(SELECT max(id) from test_table)
```

[image: Plan for max query]
[image: Trace for max query]